# Detecting classname of SVGAnimatedString

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I had a problem with a SVG map I was building, the functions triggered by 
onmouseover on g were not working. I used then

```
window.onmouseover=function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.className);
        };
```

to see if there was any problem with the classname, and then discovered than instead of the classname I was using, the system was detecting

```
SVGAnimatedString {animVal: "", baseVal: ""}
```

Something that never happened to me before the hundreds of times I've used similar code. 
Any idea how can I get the actual classname of the g elements on mouseover? Thanks

Comment: I think a good solution would be to use `element.classList` instead of `element.className`, because the classList API works on both html elements and svg elements (so long as you don't need to support obsolete browsers - I think IE11 doesn't support classList on SVG elements).

Comment: @robocat Yaas 2018 but also yaas this should be the answer

Answer (score 31):

Simplest way:

```
e.target.className.baseVal
```

Another way:

```
e.target.getAttribute("class")
```

Comment: The result to that is a blank space

Comment: That means no class name has been assigned to the element.

Comment: The second option returns 'null'. It actually has a class, that's the problem

Comment: Maybe the problem is that this element isn't getting assigned the class that you expected.  Set a breakpoint in your mouseover handler, open up e.target in your browser's DOM inspector, and check the className property.

Comment: I'm including the class manually inline, but yes, the e.target shows something different (that actually is not a class), as shown in the question. That's what I'm trying to fix, because I assign that class a particular task on mouseover

Comment: The second way works fine and has the benefit that it yields the expected string for both HTML and SVG elements.

Comment: Using `element.getAttribute('class')` doesn't help because it returns an object (the same as `element.className`). I found this using Chrome with an `<svg>` element that has no `class=` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you also set the class name inside the svg **path** tags and then try `e.target.getAttribute("class")`

That worked for me.