# Getting the href value of an anchor within an SVG using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I am using jQuery to target anchor elements within an SVG image I have created to get the value of the href assigned to the anchor element. I am then trying to toggle on and off a piece of content that has an HTML ID identical to the href of the anchor element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $('.ghb_toggle').hide()
      $('object').on( "load", (evt) => { // wait for the page has fully loaded
        const svg_doc = $("object")[0].contentDocument;
        $('a[xlink\\:href^="#"]', svg_doc )
          .on( "click", (evt) => {
            target = evt.currentTarget.href;
            console.log(target); // for debugging purposes
            $(target).toggle();
          });
      });
});
```

```html
<object data="/wp-content/uploads/GHB_Interface-v0.1.svg" width="1400" height="1200"></object>

<div class="ghb_toggle" id="gable-pediments">content1</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="gutters-downspouts">content2</div>
<div class="ghb_toggle" id="operable-shades">content3</div>
```

I am facing a problem when I assign the href value to the variable I created "target". When I output the value of my variable $(target) in the console:

```
target = evt.currentTarget.href;
console.log(target);
```

**Output:**

```
SVGAnimatedString {baseVal: "#gutters-downspouts", animVal: "#gutters-downspouts"}
```

This seems like it is successfully getting the href value of my anchor element! (the value should be "#gutters-downspouts").

However, when I try to use jQuery to then toggle the respective html element with an ID that is identical to the href value like this:

```
target = evt.currentTarget.href;
$(target).toggle();
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
```

What the heck am I doing wrong? It seems as if it thinks my variable is undefined, however, I just printed it in the console and saw it had a value!

Comment: jQuery is designed to be used with HTML, not with SVG. Sometimes jQuery does work (when SVG and HTML operate in the same way). Often it does not.

Comment: In your snippet, there aren't any `<a>` tags and there aren't any nodes with an `href`.  Can you update the snippet to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: A sample to demonstrate the problem, not your entire SVG.  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: `SVGAnimatedString {baseVal: "#gutters-downspouts", animVal: "#gutters-downspouts"}` is not a valid entry for a jquery selector - if you're getting that with `.href` then try `.href.baseVal`

Comment: Related, but possibly not a direct duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454358/2181514

Comment: @freedomn-m Using .baseVal was indeed the answer to my problem! Thank you so much for the help. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString

> SVGAnimatedString.animVal Read only This is a DOMString representing
> the animation value. If the given attribute or property is being
> animated it contains the current animated value of the attribute or
> property. If the given attribute or property is not currently being
> animated, it contains the same value as baseVal.

> SVGAnimatedString.baseVal This is a DOMString representing the base
> value. The base value of the given attribute before applying any
> animations.

So you are successfully getting the information you need but it's looking like an object with two entries. Try extracting the actual target value by using target.baseVal

(apologies that I have been unable to test this on a real system).